# Is there any way to make the first element standing alone in Gridview.builder()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to make the first item look like this. And make them all `scrollable`.

[image]

But only the items which are located in two groups are scrolling. The image at the top stays where it is. I want it scrolls too. Anyone can help?

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          
          
          Container(
            width: 550,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                // color: Colors.amber,
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    // I want his part to be scrolled.
                    image: AssetImage("assetss/fortuneteller.jpg"))),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 15,
              right: 15,
            ),
```

This is the part where items that are able to scroll are located.

```
child: Container(
              width: screenWidth / 1,
              height: screenlHeight / 1.6,
              child: GridView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return CardForFortuneTellers();
                },
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  mainAxisExtent: 500,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 0, //screenlHeight / 20,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
                itemCount: 10,
              ),
            ),
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you tried staggered_grid_view https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: I hadn't tried before you told me, but I solved with it thanks.